# Error message while running python script in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Every time I run a python script from the script editor in QGIS 2.18.3 I get this error message

[image]

After I click on "close program" the script continues like there was no error message. In total, I get a few of them, more or less one for every step of the code. The thing is that this is not a "really" error message because the code continues to run normally after I click on "close program" until the code finishes, and there is nothing wrong with the outputs of the code. The only annoying thing is that I can't "leave" the code to run by itself and I need to monitor it in order to click every time on "close program" so that the code will continue.
Does somebody had the same issue?

an example code is the following. Is it iterate over folders and does some calculation on landsat band 10. Every time it produce a new file (output) I get the error message.

```
##calibrate landsat bands v8=name
##Select_directory=Folder

import glob, os, os.path, math
import glob, os, os.path, math
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsRectangle
#Select_directory = r"C:\Users\Ran\Desktop\Manna\calibrate LS8\testing iterating"
x = "SUN_ELEVATION"
wrs_path = "WRS_PATH"
wrs_row = "WRS_ROW"
date_of_image ="DATE_ACQUIRED"  
#create a list of the directories in the folder
folder_list=[name for name in os.listdir(Select_directory) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Select_directory, name))] #list the folder names
if len(folder_list) > 0:
    a=0

    for folder in folder_list: #folder= name of a folder with only files
        folderpath = os.path.join(Select_directory,folder_list[a]) #the path to a specific folder
        a+=1
        os.chdir(folderpath)
        name_list=[] #list of file names
        for raster in glob.glob("*.tif"): #raster = tif files in specific folder
            name_list.append(raster[:21])   

        unique = set(name_list)   #get only unique values

        for c in unique: #c= unique name of landsat image (include all bands)
            for b in os.listdir(folderpath): #b= file name in a specific folder
                if (c+"_MTL") in b:
                    i = os.path.join(folderpath,b) #this expression :[source+"\\"+folder] is a path to a folder that has rasters
                    z = open(i,'r')             

                    for line, text in enumerate(z):  
                        if x in text:                
                            y = text.split("=")
                            SUN_ELEVATION = (y[1])


                        elif wrs_path in text:
                            yy = text.split("=")
                            WRS_PATH = yy[1]
                            path_temp = WRS_PATH.strip()
                            WRS_PATH1 = path_temp.replace(" ","")           
                            if len(WRS_PATH1)==2: 
                                WRS_PATH1 = "0"+WRS_PATH1

                        elif wrs_row in text:   
                            yyy = text.split("=")
                            WRS_ROW = yyy[1]
                            row_temp = WRS_ROW.strip()
                            WRS_ROW1 = row_temp.replace(" ","")
                            if len(WRS_ROW1)==2: #this is to check if the row is 2 or 3 digits
                                WRS_ROW1 = "0"+WRS_ROW1

                        elif date_of_image in text:
                            yyyy = text.split("=")
                            yyyyy = yyyy[1].split("-")
                            day = yyyyy[2]
                            month = yyyyy[1]
                            year = yyyyy[0][-2:]
                            DATE_ACQUIRED = year+month+day  


            image_suffix = "ls8_{}{}_{}".format(WRS_PATH1,WRS_ROW1,DATE_ACQUIRED)
            SUN_ELEVATION = float(y[1])
            SUN_ELEVATION1 = math.radians(SUN_ELEVATION)
            syntax = '(A>0.001)*10000*(A*0.00002-0.1)/sin('+str(SUN_ELEVATION1)+')'
            os.chdir(folderpath)

            for raster in glob.glob("*.tif"):
                if raster[:25]==c+"_B10":
                    outputName = os.path.join(folderpath,"cal_"+c+"_B10") 
                    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
                    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
                    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster, baseName)
                    outputs_GDALOGRRASTERCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:rastercalculator', rlayer,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1','(A>0)*(1000*(1321.0789/(log(774.8853/(A*0.0003342+0.1)+1))-273.15))','0',4,None,outputName)
```

Comment: It may be an an error from an external library that doesn't affect your program, did you try to debug the line doing this issue ?

Comment: You mentioned using _code_ but did not post any of it which is probably why it has been flagged. Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/229391/edit) your question to include the code you used? Maybe then others can tell you why the error occurs :)

Comment: This "error" occurs in every code that I run in QGIS, it does not matter which code. I posted this question because I thought somebody also encounter the same problem. Maybe it has something to do with multiple python interpreters\platforms that I have. On my computer I have anaconda, pycharm, QGIS, arcmap. Maybe somebody has a direction I can look for. Thanks

Comment: What do you see in `Settings` > `System` > `Environment` > `Current environment variables` at the `PYTHONHOME` variable? Something like `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27`? It may depends from it.

Comment: hi mgri, yes, it says: `C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27`. How can I continue from here?

Comment: I was expecting not... Probably you may try to set it manually again...

Comment: How do I do that? should I install QGIS again?